# Webpack loads output file bundle.js, but JavaScript from entry file index.js doesn't work

Tags: webpack

**UPD:** I think I figured it out. The problem was webpack configurations:

1. Removed the *webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/* line from the entry points.
2. Removed the *webpack/hot/only-dev-server* line from entry points.
3. Removed the *devServer.**hot*** option.

Once I've done that, the setup started working fine.

I've encountered a very strange behavior from Webpack. Webpack does load the entry index.js file as bundle.js, but the JavaScript code that I write in index.js doesn't work. Still, bundle.js has this code at the end of the file at around 9200th line.

In other words, if I run the app and open the page in a browser at localhost:8080, the page will load, the request will be sent for bundle.js, then the bundle.js file will be successfully uploaded, but nothing happens afterwards.

For example, if I write 'console.log('Hello');' or anything similar in bundle.js, it won't return anything to the console. I can't access DOM either from within bundle.js.

What is really strange is that I *can* import styles in the index.js (which gets compiled to bundle.js), and they do get applied.

- I have removed globally installed webpack to ensure I get no possible conflicts from that.
- There are no errors in the console and in the terminal.
- I have a working setup, so I compared the webpack configs, and they are nearly identical apart from using single-quotes vs double-quotes for some strings.
- I also decided to remove the code from the non-working setup, and simply copy-pasted the code into respective files from the working setup.
  Basically, I replaced code in app/router.js, server.js, package.json, webpack.config.js, views/index.pug, and src/index.js with code from working setup. I removed node_modules and yarn.lock, then I ran installation, and once everything is installed, I run the app, and... I get the same result.
- I removed babel and installed the latest possible version of babel-loader as suggested on babel-loader page on GitHub. Still no change. The app runs, but js doesn't.

Here's my webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'),
  path = require('path'),
  ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|git)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.html', '.css']
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '*': 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
  ]
};
```

And this is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-broken",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:AndSviat/test.git",
  "author": "Sviatoslav Andrushko <andsviat@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js & webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4"
  }
}
```

Here's the server.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express'),
  router = require('./app/router'),
  path = require('path'),
  PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.set('views', './views');

app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

Here's the app/router.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Hello From Express',
    heading: 'Simple App'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's the src/index.js:

```
console.log('Hello');
alert('Hello')

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('section'));
import './common.sass';
```

And src/styles.sass:

```
body
  color: #245b38
  background-color: #90baa7
```

And, finally, the views/index.pug:

```
doctype
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css")
    title= title
  body
    h1= heading
    script(src='/bundle.js')
```

What do I miss?
I think the only option left is to destroy my computer, burn my apartment, and start all over again.

PS: yesterday, I've run through Webpack guides, and it worked fine.

But when I setup everything manually, I get no errors or anything, and JavaScript doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to your webpack config your bundle.js is created in yourRootDirectory/public, but in your index.pug file in views directory your are looking for bundle.js in view directory. If copy paste bundle.js from public to view maybe it should work.

Comment: No change. The devServer.proxy property allows for redirecting all requests from localhost:8080 to localhost:3000. So when I go to localhost:8080, webpack-dev-server asks Express to handle the request. And Express router will serve the index.pug page from the views directory, but all other content will be served from '/public', because the app uses express.static. So, any requests for styles, js, and images will be served automatically from '/public'.